# android: displaying progress dialog when waiting for connection

Tags: android, loading, http-post, progressdialog

I am trying to add a progress dialog when a new activity is launched that has to wait for a response from the internet. At the moment the screen just goes black while it is waiting. Does any one know where it needs to be placed to work?

this progressDialog:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
dialog.dismiss();
```

this is in the overlayActivity extends ItemizedOverlay:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    final OverlayItem item = (OverlayItem) items.get(index);
    final Context mContext = context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle(item.getTitle())
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setPositiveButton("View Details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Profile.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", item.getSnippet());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    return true;
}
```

and this is the Profile activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.profile);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String id;

    if (extras != null) {
        id = extras.getString("id");

        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXMLFromBarId(id); // makes httpPost call
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(0);

        // rest of profile created here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use Progress dialog. Progress dialog should be used in the Profile activity.
You can use the following code:

```
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyProfileActivity.this, "","Loading..Wait.." , true);
dialog.show();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your code here
                dialog.dismiss();
    }   
}, 3000);  // 3000 milliseconds
```

Comment: `The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.` Do not forget this.

Answer (score 2):

Doing network calls in the UI thread (the thread which calls "onCreate") is a bad idea. It will stall the refresh of the UI till the network operation is completed. Instead, spawn a new thread in onCreate like so:

```
Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXMLFromBarId(id); // makes httpPost call
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(0);

        ....
   }
}
networkThread.start();
```

Also, I'd recommend using a ProgressDialog to show progress (which you can dismiss, once the code in the thread is done). Tutorial: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

**Note**: You cannot dismiss the dialog from the new thread, so you will have to use a Handler to post a message from the thread to the UI thread. Here is a tutorial for that: https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html
Example:
In your Profile activity class, add this:

```
class ProfileActivity extends Activity {
    class ProfileHandler extends Handler {
        private ProfileActivity parent;

        public ProfileHandler(ProfileActivity parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            parent.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    private ProfileHandler handler;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        handler = new ProfileHandler(this);

        Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

            String xml = XMLfunctions.getXMLFromBarId(id); // makes httpPost call
            Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(0);

            ....
            
            ProfileActivity.this.handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
        networkThread.start();
    }

    public void handleMessage(msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
        case 0:
            // Update UI here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did try this method, but unfortunately it didn't work. The activity runs and the page displays, but none of the data is getting displayed. I will look into it more to see if I can find the problem. Many thanks :)

Comment: Can you tell me where you are attempting to show the data. Like I mentioned, any attempt to update the UI in a different thread, will fail. You will have to send a Message back to the UI thread using a Handler.

Comment: The UI is updated within the thread, just after the "Element e = ...". All that is happening out side the thread is the XMLfunctions methods, which pull in the data from an XML feed.

Comment: Which is what I mentioned. You cannot update the UI from the new thread we created (networkThread). You will have to do the network operations and the item reads in the networkThread and then send a message back, which gets handled by the Handler class which you need to initialize in the onCreate() (UI thread).

Comment: I have been attempting to get this to work for over an hour with no luck. Even it the tutorial he says its hard to explain, and it just doesn't seem to work with my app. I think I will leave threads out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your time and addition. I will try working it in. Thank you